# Accessing Thermography data from a HikVision IP Camera

Tags: hikvision

i have a question as to if anyone has found a solution to accessing the Thermography result data from a HIkVision camera - what we are trying to achieve is to put the camera in a temperature monitoring mode (in this case a (DS-2TD2617B-3/PA thermal and optical bullet camera) what we want to do is on demand make a request to the camera as to the current temperature min max and average being a bonus - we have investigated and can see methods to get a current snapshot picture from the camera which is great (http://ipaddress/ISAPI/Streaming/Channels/1/picture) but we would also like to get the data itself in a simpler from to handle

has anybody experience or have done this before ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we ended up going with in the end for the particular camera to get the data was ISAPI requests such as below

Manual call to get the current temperature readings on demand
http://xxxxxxxxxxx/ISAPI/Thermal/channels/2/thermometry/1/rulesTemperatureInfo?format=json

Get thermal image picture
http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/2/picture

and to enable those we had to turn on rstp stream and web authentication to be enabled on the camera which allows ISAPI requests etc.

Comment: Hi, is there a data-sheet on these thermometry API calls? I'd like to get raw thermal data from my DS-2TD1217B-3/PA camera

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the next Requests

It is used to get temperature measurement relate preset info capability.

/ISAPI/Thermal/channels/[ID]/thermometry/[SID]/capabilities

/ISAPI/Thermal/channels/[ID]/thermometry/[SID]

Comment: this is exactly what we ended up doing to get both pictures and thermal data 

Manual call to get the current temperature readings on demand
http://xxxxxxxxxxx/ISAPI/Thermal/channels/2/thermometry/1/rulesTemperatureInfo?format=json 

Get thermal image picture
http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/2/picture